# React-native: how to change row's content or style while swiping?

Tags: react-native, swipe

I want to have a functionality similar to Google Inbox ([demo](https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2015/06/Inbox3.gif)), when swiping an item causes a change of the background color and size of the icon.

My implementation has a `ListView` of [`Swipeable`](https://github.com/jshanson7/react-native-swipeable) components as rows and I want to change the content or style of a row (in the right pane for example) based on the swipe position.
In order to have the ListView to re-render while swiping I added a `pos` state which I set using the `onPanAnimatedValueRef` prop of the `Swipeable`.

The problem is that the `ListView` doesn't re-render and nothing changes.

```
<ListView
    ...
    renderRow={(data) => (
                <Swipeable rightContent={
                        <View><Text>{this.state.pos}</Text></View>
                    }
                    ...
                    onPanAnimatedValueRef={(pan) => { 
                        pan.addListener(val => {
                            this.setState({
                                pos: val.x
                            });
                    }}>
                    {data}
                </Swipeable>
    )}
/>
```

Do you see any problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the `Swipeable` in your own component, hold state there and your animation logic. It is not the ListView's responsibility to rerender the whole thing since the data hasn't changed, just your row itself.

Alternatively, you could change the data via `setState` to the `ListView`'s data source (which presumably was based in state and hence force a rerender but this is a less efficient path)

Comment: Very good idea. Let me try it and see how would it work. Thank you!